# Access Violation error when seeding db information using enity.frameworkcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, access-violation

I'm creating a new application for creating and transporting reports in ASP.NET Core. So, I used entity framework to to create a database using code first. However, one of the classes called "WfStepsDefinition" does not let a foreign key called "WfDefinitionId" have repeating values.

I checked the database by reading the create statement and using queries to insert the appropriate data. So, I don't believe the problem is rooted in database constraints.

Here is the two values I'm using dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync() on that returns errors:

```
            new WfStepsDefinition() { Ordr = 1, WfDefinitionId = 1, WfStepTypeId = 1},
            new WfStepsDefinition() { Ordr = 1, WfDefinitionId = 1, WfStepTypeId = 1}
```

Here are two values I'm using dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync() on that do not returns errors:

```
            new WfStepsDefinition() { Ordr = 1, WfDefinitionId = 1, WfStepTypeId = 1},
            new WfStepsDefinition() { Ordr = 1, WfDefinitionId = 2, WfStepTypeId = 1}
```

Here is the class for WfStepsDefinitions while this would traditionally be a use a composite primary key it inherits from a base entity that includes Id as a primary key and other values:

```
    public class WfStepsDefinition : Entity
        {
            public int Ordr { get; set; }

            // n-1 relationship
            public int WfDefinitionId { get; set; }
            public WfDefinition WfDefinition { get; set; }

            public int WfStepTypeId { get; set; }
            public WfStepType WfStepType { get; set; }
        }
```

For reference this SQL statement is how it is used in the database

```
    SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
          ,[UpdatedBy]
          ,[UpdatedOn]
          ,[Ordr]
          ,[WfDefinitionId]
          ,[WfStepTypeId]
    FROM [Pwdx].[dbo].[WfStepsDefinition]
```

For expected results I should be able to use repeating values for WfDefinitionId such as

```
    new WfStepsDefinition() { Ordr = 1, WfDefinitionId = 1, WfStepTypeId = 1},
            new WfStepsDefinition() { Ordr = 1, WfDefinitionId = 1, WfStepTypeId = 1}
```

should not return any errors

This is the last batch from the output before the IIS exits.

```
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
    SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM [WfStepsDefinition] AS [w])
         THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END
     The program '[31648] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

EDIT: Figured something out

```
    public class WfDefinition : Entity
        {
            public string Description { get; set; }

            // n-1 relationship
            public int PwReleaseTypeId { get; set; }
            public PwReleaseType pwReleaseType { get; set; }

            // 1-n relationships
            //public List<WfStepsDefinition> WfStepsDefinitions { get; set; } = new List<WfStepsDefinition>();
        }
```

how come the error goes away when the reference to the 1-n class is removed?

Comment: Could it be something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253700/access-violation-exception-during-access-of-field-of-object

Comment: Are you defining the relations between the entities on the "OnModelCreating"?